# Magento admin 404 not found

Tags: magento2, 404-page

I installed magento2 but when I click on admin url its redirect me to 404 page any idea?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Please specify the version as well

Comment: Are you sure you're going to the right URL? From the command line run:

php bin/magento info:adminuri

Does it match the URL you're trying to access?